# Upgrading ag-grid angular version

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I updated the ag-grid to version 19.

The problem is that the sidebar is completely distorted.

When inspecting the element in dev tools i noticed there is no css rules to the side bar.(which completely changed in this version as far as i know)

Image here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6iRA.jpg

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AgGrid's free version has a [new npm package name from version 19](https://medium.com/ag-grid/introducing-version-19-of-ag-grid-a7fc97714843) - now 'ag-grid-community' instead of 'ag-grid'.

Perhaps you are still using the old package name, in which case you'll need to update all references to 'ag-grid' to be 'ag-grid-community'.

Comment: And also need to update to the right css file in 'styles' folder. thanks